# ASP.NET MVC 3 jquery : French accent characters are showing as #233 characters on screen

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, localization, diacritics

I have **ASP.NET MVC 3** application having resource files in *english* and *french*.
A text '**Sélectionner la pharmacie**' is stored in a french resource file.

When the value is read from resource files with razor syntax, it shows
'**S#233;lectionner la pharmacie**' instead of '**Sélectionner la pharmacie**'.

```
e.g.
@MyResources.Strings_Resources.lbl_SelectPharmacy
```

Is there a way I can make it show the french accent characters ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect that your text is already encoded and razor is trying to encode it *again* (it encodes all outputs)

Try with

```
@Html.Raw(MyResources.Strings_Resources.lbl_SelectPharmacy)
```

Comment: Most probably, this is not the case. There is no reason why somebody would store HTML-encoded data into resources. But ASP.NET’s default HTML encoder encodes (for reasons unknown to me) all characters between 160–256. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/9456114/304138 (and the question). Using Html.Raw is most often just a security hole waiting to happen.

Answer (score 4):

First check your master page, you have set UTF-8

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
```

```
<system.web>
    <globalization enableclientbasedculture="true" uiculture="auto" culture="auto">

    <!-- Use above or below <globalization> line, based on your site -->

    <globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
</system.web>
```

If you have set this already then try below setup:-

```
<asp:Label Text="<%$ Resources:Strings, MyGlobalResource %>" runat="server" />
<asp:Label Text="<%$ Resources:MyLocalResource %>" runat="server" />
```

```
<%= HttpContext.Current.GetLocalResourceString("~/YOURASPXPAGE", "MyLocalResource", CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture) %>
```

Refer this URL for more info:-

1. **[ASP.NET MVC 3 Internationalization](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx)**
2. **[ASP.NET MVC - Localization Helpers](http://www.eworldui.net/blog/post/2008/05/ASPNET-MVC---Localization.aspx)**

Comment: I don't think the problem is the charset since the character is showed encoded, not gârbl€d™

Comment: Like Bettle Midler said, you are my hero!

Comment: adding above line in<system.web> worked for me thanks a lot.<meta ...> was doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I was having problem showing French characters in `textarea` through JQuery/Javascript (asp.net mvc).

```
myArry.push("\r\n" + "SÉRIE CERVICALE");
$('#myTextArea').val(myArry);
```

> Result : SÃ‰RIE CERVICALE

Adding this line in Web.config worked for me.

```
<system.web>
<globalization fileEncoding="utf-8" requestEncoding="utf-8"responseEncoding="utf-8"/>
</system.web>
```

> Result : SÉRIE CERVICALE