# Special characters in html output

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I want characters like 'ø' to be printed directly, but in the source 'ø' shows up as `&#248;`

If the output goes through `Html.Encode()` it won't render the correct character, but `&#248;`

in the config I have

```
<globalization
  fileEncoding="utf-8"
  requestEncoding="utf-8"
  responseEncoding="utf-8"
  culture="nb-NO"
  uiCulture="nb-NO"
/>
```

Source:

```
<li><%: Html.ActionLink("Støvletter", "ListProducts", "Tag", new { tag = "Stovletter" }, null)%></li>
```

This outputs:

```
<li><a href="/Tag/Stovletter">St&#248;vletter</a></li>
```

But output should look like:

```
<li><a href="/Tag/Stovletter">Støvletter</a></li>
```

Comment: What is the 'source' in this case? You need to provide more context.

Comment: I updated with source and output.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov: Because if I run my strings through Html.Encode() it is presented literally as "&#248;" to the user.

Comment: Did you try direct output `<%=` instead of html encoded `<%:`?

Comment: @WiktorZychla That wouldn't change anything here, since it's the `Html.ActionLink` method that does the encoding, and it outputs an `MvcHtmlString` which doesn't get encoded again.

Comment: @WiktorZychla This does indeed solve half of my problems, would u mind posting it as an answer and I will accept it. Now if I could only turn off the encoding in the Html.ActionLink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to create output with `<%=` instead of html encoded `<%:`

(I post this after your positive comment to my comment)

Comment: I have a hard time coming up with a situation where that's the correct choice. I'd rather use `IHtmlString`, `HtmlString` or `MvcHtmlString`.

Comment: I selected this as accepted answer since it fixed my problem in all places except using Html.ActionLink()

Answer (score 3):

This might not be the answer you are looking for but it is nevertheless interesting.

If you look at the `HttpEncoder` source code it makes provision for [custom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.util.httpencoder.current.aspx) `HtmlEncoders` to be used instead of the default [WebUtility.HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee388364.aspx)

I have played around and found the [HtmlEncoder called AntiXSS](http://wpl.codeplex.com/) from Microsoft encodes these characters correctly.

I installed it using [Nuget](http://nuget.org/packages/AntiXSS):

```
PM> Install-Package AntiXSS
```

And then updated my `web.config` as such:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime encoderType="Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXssEncoder, 
AntiXssLibrary" />
    ....
</system.web>
```

Both normal output and Html.ActionLinks seem to work.

Comment: I can't find the correct source code file in their repository. Can you post the link? The functions I found were called differently, and also by default encoded all characters that aren't on a small whitelist.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, I used Resharper's to automatically download the code from Microsoft's servers.  Here is a snippet of the code in `WebUtility.Encode` that I am looking at:  http://tinyurl.com/75j3njm, See line 74-81.  ø oridinal value 248 and thus encoded.  The code must have been compiled with the `ENTITY_ENCODE_HIGH_ASCII_CHARS` compiler directive for this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK this is not possible unless you roll your own custom HTML encoding routine (which I absolutely would recommend you against).

The resulting HTML is correct and the character is properly displayed on the client browser. HTML is meant to be read by programs (web browsers) in order to present it to a human readable form, not by humans.

```
<li><a href="/Tag/Stovletter">St&#248;vletter</a></li>
```

is a perfectly valid HTML that will be displayed like this on the client browser:

[image]

Comment: Entity encoding characters that have no special meaning in html/xml is pretty stupid IMO. That's why we have UTF8. It's certainly valid, but IMO very ugly.

Comment: Also IMO human readability is a feature of html. Else we could have used a binary format, which would be more compact, and easier to parse.

Comment: @CodeInChaos, user agents don't really have the notion of `ugliness` as we humans :-) They understand the notion of validity of a markup. As far as the binary format is concerned, this exactly what you should do with your site in production => remove all whitespaces, gzip it and so on. Have you looked at the http://google.com HTML source code recently?

Comment: When I look at google html I certainly see that they don't use entity encoding on higher unicode codepoints.

Comment: I realize this displays correctly to the end user, but I want the HTML file that is sent to the user to be UTF-8 (which it is technically, but I also want it to not encode special characters).

Comment: @OMGKurtNilsen, I am afraid that in this case you will have to built your custom html encoder method. You will also have to build your custom versions of the Html helpers because all of them use the built-in encoder and then use those custom helpers.