# read value from resource string text change to "S&#237;"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using resource string for Spanish language in my web application
one resource string has value 'Sí' in Spanish language.
when I use 'Sí' string in my view it change to "Sí" 
How do I resolve the issue?

the resource string is 
res_Option_Yes: Sí

My view is

```
$.prompt('@Resource.deleteConfirm', {
        title: '@Resource.title',
        buttons: { '@Resource.res_Option_Yes': true, '@Resource.res_Option_No': false },
        submit: function (e, v, m, f) {
-- code
});
```

when I debug the application I can see

```
buttons: { 'S&#237;': true, 'No': false },
```

Comment: I have resolved using @Html.Raw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8180123/asp-net-mvc-3-jquery-french-accent-characters-are-showing-as-233-characters-o

Answer (score 1):

It (`&#237;`) is encoded string of 'í'.  So in HTML you have to decode it. Use below line in your view to decode it, this will be helpful to you.

```
@Html.Raw(Resource.res_Option_Yes)
```

**OR**

```
@System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode(Resource.res_Option_Yes)
```

**OR**

```
@System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Resource.res_Option_Yes)
```